# Angularjs json how to get property name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to display the property name as the table header and here is my code

```
      <table>
          <th ng-repeat="auditorium in auditoriums">
                {{ auditorium.NAME }}
          </th>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="auditorium in auditoriums" ng-if="$index > 0">
                  <td>{{ auditorium.NAME }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSBUILDINGNAME }}</td>
                 <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE }}</td>
                  <td>{{ auditorium.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

example of the json code would be { "NAME : "ABC", "ADDRESSPOSTALCODE" : "CBA" }
i want to display the 'name' and 'addresspostalcode' as my table header. Would that be possible? Help would be appreciated ! ( It's an array of objects )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,val) in auditorium">
                {{ key }}
 </th>
```

Comment: Cool, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use ng-repeat over an object, you can just access using

```
{{ auditoriums.NAME }}
```

and

```
{{ auditoriums.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}
```

Comment: Mine's an array, sorry didn't clarify properly

Comment: post your array then

Comment: I am trying to access the "name" not the "abc" stored

Comment: thats what im saying post the array